# VBA Use Vlookup to place a Value into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA and this has me stumped. I hope there is an easy way to do this. I know the following doesn't work, but it's an easy way to show what I'd like to do:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(date, .Range("A:A"), 2, False) = String
```

Basically I want to look up a date in a column A, go to the second Column and insert the string.

I've searched and can't find what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance,

Cory

Answer (score 1):

We can use *MATCH()* to find the row and deposit the string with the correct offset from column **A**:

```
Sub Spiral()
    Dim s As String, i As Long

    s = "whatever"
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Date), Range("A:A"))
    Cells(i, 2).Value = s
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I appreciate everything you guys do!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Range.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746)

```
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = .Range("A:A").Find(date, , , xlWhole)
If Not cell Is Nothing Then cell(, 2) = String ' or cell.Offset(, 1) = String
```